# I can have a tag both in "Favourite Tags" & in "Ignored Tags"

Tags: bug, tag-watching, ignored-tags

If you have a tag both in the "Favourite Tags" & in "Ignored Tags" it will be ignored anyway (as if it's in the ignored list); you get no warning about this when adding a tag to either list.

This is perhaps a slightly silly thing to do; in my case, I've made fairly large list of "Ignored Tags" over the years with topics I have zero knowledge of, including [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) & [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).
In March I got hired as a Ruby on Rails developer, and by now I've gained enough Ruby & Rails knowledge to maybe answer questions on these subjects, so I added it to "Favourite Tags", forgetting I had added it to the ignored list several years ago...

Having a tag in both lists makes no sense, and should IMHO be prevented by the system. It's also confusing (it took me a while to figure out why the questions weren't being highlighted as I expected).

Comment: I agree this should not be able to happen.

Comment: Old network meta post on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161220/why-can-i-both-favorite-and-ignore-the-same-same-tag